# Removing text and changing bgimage in a div embedded in a div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

*Solved it! Sorry for putting the solution here, haven't got enough rep to post answer :(*

I'm kinda new with JQuery and I've made myself a bit of a challange here. I have a homepage, with tiles as menu and every tile has a title, but when I hover my mouse over each tile, I'd like to hide the title and show an image instead. I was thinking to do it with a css background-image trick, through a JQuery script.

-------- Heavy Editing from here -------

So, I couldn't figure the problem, I went through all the stuff you guys wrote me and then I figured, I'm doing a bad approach. I changed it and voila! It's working!

Here's the html:

```
<li class="tile darkblue">
    <div class="tile-title"><p>Flyers</p></div>
    <div class="tile-image hide"><img src="images/flyers.png" alt="" /></div>
</li>
```

Here's the css:

```
.tile
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4.5em;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tile div
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}

.tile div p
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.tile img
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tile .hide
{
    display: none;
}
```

and the JQ script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.tile').each(function(){

    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $('.tile-title', this).css('display', 'none');
        $('.tile-image', this).css('display', 'table');
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function(){
        $('.tile-title', this).css('display', 'table');
        $('.tile-image', this).css('display', 'none');
    });     
    });

});
```

Thank you for Your help, I would think the idea through again, without you're help!

Comment: $this != $(this) -- line 9 of your second block,  and uh, more like $(this).css('background-image', 'url(somelinkhere)');,  and $(this).css('background-image', 'none'); some help I think.  I think you have some syntax errors, see if correcting those helps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are using the bg variable without defining it.

Answer (score 0):

DrCord is right, you're passing bg as a string containing the link to the image but there's nowhere in the script that defines what bg is

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to replace :

> $("tile")

to

> $(".tile")

and of course check all syntax of code and using of undefined variables - such as 'bg'

Comment: Yeah, Just figured the $(".tile") and according to you, I've replace the 'bg' to 'image'. Now the image doesn't show, but when I remove the cursor from the tile, the text goes up to the upper left corner, instead of being at the middle. :(